# How to change the dynamic baseUrl Laravel + Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, base-url

How do I set the baseUrl so if I switch from server to server on the frontend (Vue.js), it changes dynamically to baseUrl?

I show my code axios-auth.js code:

```
 import axios from 'axios'

 const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://mvp.test/api/public/api/'
   // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' for testing localhost
 });
```

and my .env file which have standard code for laravel.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [the official mix documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#environment-variables), you can use an environment variable by creating a key in your `.env` prefixed with `MIX_`:

```
MIX_BASE_URL=http://mvp.test/api/public/api/
```

And run `php artisan config:clear` to be sure the new config is set.

Then, in javascript you can access the variable inside the `process.env` object:

```
process.env.MIX_BASE_URL
```

So you can simply use it like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.MIX_BASE_URL
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is process.env.MIX_BASE_URL ?

Comment: It's a variable that laravel mix process will automatically translate to the content of the key `MIX_BASE_URL` in your `.env`. So, in this example, it would be the string `http://mvp.test/api/public/api/`

Comment: in .env i set MIX_BASE_URL=http://mvp.test/api/public/api/ 
in axios.auth.js i set 
const instance = axios.create({
  process.env.MIX_BASE_URL
});
 
error not except . ??
@gbalduzzi

Comment: Okey but my .env read my app_url not mix_base_url 
Did i need change anythink in config.app.php ?
Can I testing on localhost?

Comment: You can add rows to your .env with the options you need, such as MIX_BASE_URL